# Form's submit not working on a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a form on a modal using bpopup plugin and foundation framework. When I click the submit button nothing happens.. Here is the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <input type="email" name="myemail" required="required" class="large-12       columns" placeholder="enter your email"/>
    <input type="password" name="mypassword" required="required" class="large-12 columns" placeholder="enter your password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button round success large-12 columns"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might that be your `action="checklogin.php"` gone 404?

Comment: @AlanMachado I checked, and that's not the problem.. I guess it may have something to do with bpopup or foundation